# Show that a cubic Diophantine equation has no solutions

Tags: diophantine-equations

Show that the Diophantine equation $x^3+117y^3 = 5$ has no solutions.

I tried using like an odd and even argument for $x$ but it doesn't seem to work because it doesn't matter if $x$ is odd or even. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: The cubes modulo $9$ are $0$, $1$, and $-1$.

Comment: That is really clever! How did you know to use modulo 9?

Comment: You could also use modulo $3$ I believe.

Comment: Conceivably.  But not directly, since modulo $3$ our equation becomes $x^3\equiv 2\pmod{3}$, which **does** have a solution.